# How to work with this type of column like this?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, databricks

I don't how to get the relevant information from this SQL column type:

```
array<
 struct<
  day_of_week:string,
  start:bigint,
  duration:bigint,
  enabled:boolean,
  created_at:timestamp,
  deleted_at:timestamp
  >
>
```

This column has information about the daily opening hours of the restaurants in the database. There have restaurants that have changed their daily ours of operations and for this reason some of the lines in the SQL table I really don't need. All is need are the current hours of operation of all the restaurants.

This is a sample of the column I am trying to get the information from looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "day_of_week": "4",
    "start": 64800000,
    "duration": 359,
    "enabled": false,
    "created_at": "2018-02-23T10:47:15.033+0000",
    "deleted_at": "2018-10-22T18:27:40.403+0000"
  },
  {
    "day_of_week": "7",
    "start": 64800000,
    "duration": 359,
    "enabled": true,
    "created_at": "2018-10-22T18:29:11.030+0000",
    "deleted_at": null
  },
  {
    "day_of_week": "5",
    "start": 64800000,
    "duration": 359,
    "enabled": true,
    "created_at": "2018-10-22T18:29:11.030+0000",
    "deleted_at": null
  },
  {
    "day_of_week": "6",
    "start": 64800000,
    "duration": 359,
    "enabled": false,
    "created_at": "2018-10-22T18:27:40.397+0000",
    "deleted_at": "2018-10-22T18:27:42.074+0000"
  },
  {
    "day_of_week": "7",
    "start": 64800000,
    "duration": 359,
    "enabled": false,
    "created_at": "2018-10-22T18:27:40.397+0000",
    "deleted_at": "2018-10-22T18:27:42.074+0000"
  },
  {
    "day_of_week": "1",
    "start": 64800000,
    "duration": 359,
    "enabled": false,
    "created_at": "2018-10-22T18:27:42.069+0000",
    "deleted_at": "2018-10-22T18:29:11.035+0000"
  },
  {
    "day_of_week": "6",
    "start": 64800000,
    "duration": 359,
    "enabled": true,
    "created_at": "2018-10-22T18:29:11.030+0000",
    "deleted_at": null
  },
  {
    "day_of_week": "7",
    "start": 64800000,
    "duration": 359,
    "enabled": false,
    "created_at": "2018-10-22T18:27:42.069+0000",
    "deleted_at": "2018-10-22T18:29:11.035+0000"
  },
  {
    "day_of_week": "2",
    "start": 64800000,
    "duration": 359,
    "enabled": false,
    "created_at": "2018-02-23T10:47:15.033+0000",
    "deleted_at": "2018-10-22T18:27:40.403+0000"
  },
```

I am not interested in this piece of information because it was deleted on 2018-10-22:

```
[{"day_of_week":"4","start":64800000,"duration":359,"enabled":false,
"created_at":"2018-02-23T10:47:15.033+0000","deleted_at":"2018-10-22T18:27:40.403+0000"}
```

But I am interested in all the all of the parts of this column that looks like this because it shows the operational hours for day_of_week: 7.

```
"day_of_week":"7","start":64800000,"duration":359,"enabled":true,
"created_at":"2018-10-22T18:29:11.030+0000","deleted_at":null
```

I have tried this to get all the elements of the column but it only returns the first like of the cell and nothing more:

```sql
LATERAL VIEW explode(shifts.`day_of_week`) exploded_table as day_of_week
LATERAL VIEW explode(shifts.`start`) exploded_table as start
LATERAL VIEW explode(shifts.`enabled`) exploded_table as enabled
LATERAL VIEW explode(shifts.`duration`) exploded_table as duration
```

Can someone please help me with this!!!

Additionally, I imagine `"start":64800000` refers to the opening time

and `"duration":359` duration of time the restaurant is open. But I am also clueless how to interpret these figures. I don't know if `"start":64800000` refers to 7am, 8am, 9am ?? and if "duration":359 7 hours, 9 hours??

Sorry for such a long post but I am new to SQL and on here is my only real resource for finding out things I am clueless about.

Thanks in advance for any help offered.

Comment: What is a complete Row and what is expected output? Are you saying, if the `deleted_at` is not null, it should be ignored?

Comment: Correct. If    deleted_at    is not null it should be ignored.

Comment: I want all the rows that are not null. In that way I am able to get the most recent daily operational hours for each restaurant.

Comment: Something like: https://imgur.com/a/bFcoSz3?

Comment: Yes.  I am looking for something like this. Only that in my case want only the rows where    delete_at is null.

Comment: change the last query from `is not null` to `is null`.

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR:**

For a dataframe `df` with schema:

```
key:integer
data:array
  element:struct
    day_of_week:string
    start:decimal(38,0)
    duration:decimal(38,0)
    enabled:boolean
    created_at:string
    deleted_at:string
```

which is registered as temp table `test` can be exploded with:

```
select key, a.ed.day_of_week,
  a.ed.start, a.ed.duration,
  a.ed.enabled, a.ed.created_at, a.ed.deleted_at
from (select key, explode(data) as ed from global_temp.test) a
where a.ed.deleted_at is null
```

See: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bu86b.jpg